# Sort Strings in alphabetical orders

Tags: string, sorting, haskell

I have to program a function

```
sort3 :: String -> String -> String -> (String, String, String)
```

that sorts by function `(<=)` (also we can use min or max)

for example:

```
sort3 "Is" "This" "Food"
("Food", "Is", "This")

sort3 "Car" "45" "Table"
("45","Car","Table")
```

Comment: What is not workging with your approach? Can you show a fair attempt and explain what is not working. Lack of experience is not an excuse for lack of effort.

Comment: sort3 :: String -> String -> String -> (String, String, String)
sort3 "" "" "" = (<=) "" ((<=) "" "")

This is my best try...
Maybe now you can see why, I cannot understand anything yet :/

Comment: Are you restricted in any way as to use of library functions? With `sort` from `Data.List` which sorts a list, this is a 1-liner.

Comment: Don't put code in a comment; add it directly to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When sorting three strings *a*, *b*, and *c*, there are six ways in which the strings can be ordered:

1. *(a, b, c)*;
2. *(a, c, b)*;
3. *(b, a, c)*;
4. *(b, c, a)*;
5. *(c, a, b)*; and
6. *(c, b, a)*.

In these answers, the relation *e<sub>1</sub>≤e<sub>2</sub>≤e<sub>3</sub>* should hold, with *e<sub>i</sub>* the *i*-th element in the tuple.

This thus means that you can implement the function in the following manner:

```
sort3 :: Ord a => a -> a -> a -> (a, a, a)
sort3 a b c | … <= … && … <= … = (…, …, …)
            | … <= … && … <= … = (…, …, …)
            | ⋮
```

As an example, I here demonstrate how to implement a `sort2`. I leave `sort3` as an exercise:

```
sort2 :: Ord a => a -> a -> (a, a)
sort2 a b | a <= b = (a, b)
          | otherwise = (b, a)
```

Note that you can use `sort2` when you implement `sort3`. Indeed, you can make use of three `sort2` calls to sort a 3-tuple correctly. This is however a slightly more *advanced* approach. I suggest that you first aim to implement `sort3` without `sort2`, and then aim to implement it in terms of `sort2`.